# How do i use the command that uses mention on discord.js bot

Tags: discord, discord.js

Ok so I have made a command, that sends an embed on users info

```js
case 'playerinfo'

const embed = new discord.MessageEmbed()
  .setTitle('User information')
  .addField('Player Name', message.author.username)
  .addField('Current server', message.guild.name)
  .setColor(0x34eb8f)
  .setThumbnail(message.author.displayAvatarURL())

message.channel.send(embed)
```

now what it does is if I do `!playerinfo`, it tells us our username, and our profile picture and the server we are using it on. But what I want it to do is that if I type `!playerinfo @randomname`, I want it to give info on that player. Please tell me how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `message.mentions.users` to get the mentioned user, if that is not provided then it'd just use your own user

```js
case 'playerinfo'

const user = message.mentions.users.first() || message.author
const embed = new discord.MessageEmbed()
  .setTitle('User information')
  .addField('Player Name', user.username)
  .addField('Current server', message.guild.name)
  .setColor(0x34eb8f)
  .setThumbnail(user.displayAvatarURL())

message.channel.send(embed)
```

Comment: Thanks alot. This will help.

Comment: You're welcome and welcome to SO, if an answer solves your question then accept it using the tick mark next to it others can know what worked and that the question has been answered